# How do you get a runtime path for the current file in Racket?

Tags: racket

Suppose I have a file called "test.rkt" for which I want to have its absolute path available at runtime. I know that the best way to do this is to bind it using:

```
(define-runtime-path orig-file "test.rkt")
```

However, for reflection purposes, I would like to be able to do this **without knowing the name of the current file**. For example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
(define-runtime-path-self orig-file)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#%variable-reference`, which (IIRC) is the low-level reflective magic behind `define-runtime-path`:

```
(resolved-module-path-name
 (variable-reference->resolved-module-path
  (#%variable-reference)))
```

---

There's also the `syntax/location` library:

```
(require syntax/location)
(quote-source-file)
```

but **beware** that if you compile the file in one location and then move source file and `compiled/` directory to another location, the program will print the location where it was *compiled*, not where it was *run*.

---

There's also a way that goes through syntax objects and module-path-indexes, but that's more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Does `(find-system-path 'run-file)` or `(simple-form-path (find-system-path 'run-file))` work for you?